# Cannot load bootstrap css for carousel in angular

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am using Angular6 and the [ngCarousel](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples) that it is supposed to work right away, using the bootstrap styles.

My problem is that, even thought the ngCarousel is functional (clicking previous or next goes to another image)  , the style is wrong. Small images do not center. Big images fit the width, but keep their original height and they appear cropped.

I had a bootstrap CDN link in the `src/index.html` in the angular project
like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="abc123" crossorigin="anonymous">` in the header and it was working. Using bootstrap `col-lg-6` and `clo-lg-6` classes also worked. The only problems where the those in the carousel.

But I thought that is why the carousel is not properly styled and I removed it. I downloaded the `bootstrap.css` file and put it in the `styles` of `angular.json` like

```
"styles": ["../node_modules/ol/ol.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/bootstrap.css"
            ],
```

but now it is worst, since there is no bootstrap styling at all.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: Did you add bootstrap to you project? `npm i -S bootstrap` The angular-cli should link the styles automatically.

Comment: I compared the style of the `bootstrap.css` with the one in the examples in the ngBootstrap site. There is this missing in the `bootstrap.css` . If you add this, then the images are displayed fine. `ngb-carousel .carousel-item img{
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      vertical-align: middle;
  }`

Comment: using bootstrap via <link rel="stylesheet"... > in index.html is fine; if you look at the demo on https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples ...the class which ensures image responsiveness is "ngb-carousel .carousel-item img" which is not present in bootstrap.css ...and without it you get the same behavior as you are getting; perhaps the authors should have mentioned that we need to add this class to the component.css